# SQL Select a value from the history table based on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, which one table (table A) contains the users' payment data, and the other (Table B) contains the users' rank history.

```
Table A
IDNO   LName   FName  Start_Date   PayType     Current_Rank
------------------------------------------------------------
SJ01   Smith   John   11/13/2016   Cert             AC
DJ01   Doe     Jack   10/20/2020   Assignment       BC

Table B
IDNO  Date       Rank
----------------------
SJ01  10/01/2010  CAP
SJ01  10/01/2016  BC
SJ01  10/01/2020  AC
DJ01  01/01/2010  LT
DJ01  01/01/2015  CAP
DJ01  01/01/2020  BC
```

I need to show the user's rank according to the start_date from the table A and bring in the rank from the table B. So my end result can look like this:

```
IDNO   LName   FName  Start_Date   PayType         Rank
------------------------------------------------------------
SJ01   Smith   John   11/13/2016   Cert             BC
DJ01   Doe     Jack   10/20/2020   Assignment       BC
```

How can I join these two tables and compare the dates, so that I can bring in the rank from the history table based on the start_date from the table A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another very simple way is to just select the corresponding `Rank` directly using a correlated query

```
select a.*, 
 (select top(1) [rank] from TableB b
  where b.idno=a.idno and a.start_date>b.date
  order by b.date desc) as [Rank]
from TableA a
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
select a.* , c.Rank From TableA a
cross apply (select top 1 * from tableB b
        where a.IdNo = b.IDno 
        and a.Start_Date > b.date
        order by b.date desc
     ) c
```

Comment: @Serg Thanks, but not quite. The query selects the first rank in the history for the respective user. For example, it selects the CAP rank for John Smith, where it should be the BC rank.

Comment: @LucasC922 then `order by b.date desc` , see updated asnwer

Answer (score 1):

```sql
;WITH CTE  
AS  
(
    SELECT A.IDNO,A.LName,A.FName,A.Start_Date,A.PayType,B.Rank,RNo=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.IDNO ORDER BY B.DATE DESC)  
    FROM    Table_B B  
            JOIN Table_A A ON B.IDNO=A.IDNO AND A.Start_Date>=B.Date  
)   SELECT IDNO,LName,FName,Start_Date,PayType,Rank  
    FROM CTE WHERE RNo=1  
    ORDER BY Start_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select idno, lname, fname, start_date, paytype, pp.rank current_rank
from 
(select xx.idno, xx.rank, min(xx.datediff) from 
(select  tableA.idno, tableA.start_date - tableB.date datediff, tableB.rank
from tableA, tableB
where tableA.idno = tableB.idno) XX
group by xx.idno, xx.rank)pp,
tableA
where tableA.idno = pp.idno
```